# ClojureScript macro error: "Can't def ns-qualified name"

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What's causing this error?

```
(defmacro defn+
  [name & stmts]
  `(defn htrhrthtrh ~@stmts)) 

(defn+ init
  []
  (js/alert "hi"))
```

--

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: Can't def ns-qualified name
(not (namespace sym))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`htrhrthtrh` gets namespace-qualified by syntax-quote in the output, so the result looks like

```
(defn some.namespace/htrhrthtrh [] (js/alert "hi"))
```

which is incorrect, as explained in the exception message.

Presumably you'll want to use `~name` in place of `htrhrthtrh` to include the name argument to `defn+` in the output; this, or anything along similar lines, would fix the problem. To hard-wire this exact name you'd have to say `~'htrhrthtrh`.